# How to remove entire html element along with all children on JQuery button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, dynamic

Here is my dilemma:

When clicking on the search button on my JQuery dialog a request is sent to my servlet. That servlet determines which page to return. Either the result JSP page or route the user back to the search form JSP with an additional attribute/string that I display in a JQuery dialog that pops up when the html page loads. Then when I make a valid search and the servlet routes the user to the result page, then when I click the back button on the browser the notFound dialog pops up! I do not want this and have tried to remove the form element that instantiated that dialog. See source below.

Here is my element and the corresponding javascript/jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#searchForm").dialog(
                {
                    height : 400,
                    width : 450,
                    resizable : false,
                    draggable : false,
                    open : function(event, ui) {
                        $(this).parent().children().children(
                                '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                    },
                    title : "Search",
                    closeOnEscape : false,
                    buttons : {
                        "Search" : function() {
                            if ($("#name").val().length >= 1) {
                                $("#searchForm").submit();
                            } else {
                                $("#error").dialog("open");
                            }
                        },
                        "Main Menu" : function() {
                            window.location.href = "/";
                        }
                    }
                });
        $("#error").dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            resizable : false,
            draggable : false,
            title : "Error!",
            buttons : {
                "OK" : function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        ***$("#notFound").dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            resizable : false,
            draggable : false,
            title : "Nothing Found!",
            buttons : {
                "OK" : function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    var div = document.getElementById('notFound');
                    if (div) {
                        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                    }
                }
            }
        });***
    });
</script>

<body>
    <%
        if (message != null) {
    %>
    <form id="notFound">
        <p><%=message%></p>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#notFound").dialog("open");
            });
        </script>
    </form>
    <%
        }
    %>
....
```

Why does the element with the id notFound and its children not get removed from the page's source and DOM? How can I remove

```
<form id="notFound">
            <p><%=message%></p>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $("#notFound").dialog("open");
                });
            </script>
        </form>
```

on the OK: function() of the #notFound dialog? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#notFound").hide();` or `$("#notFound").remove();`

Comment: your solution only hides the content inside the dialog where I want the dialog to be removed from the html document

Comment: The "remove()" method will remove the element and all children from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple

```
$("#notFound").replaceWith("");
```

or

```
 $("#notFound").remove();
```

would work.